# How to create User in React-relay/GraphQL

Tags: reactjs

I'm new to React relay. I've read documentation but still it is not clear. What is the proper way to create something with react-relay?

Comment: With mutations https://facebook.github.io/relay/docs/guides-mutations.html

Comment: There is not data to mutate and it's a top Node

Comment: mutations i just the name of the operation in graphql / relay. This is how you create data.